# Fill missing year and week values dynamically based on series in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

have a csv with 2 columns. The file contains some missing year-week values based on the series.

Input:-

```
Date       A   
2019-51   10 
2020-04   20
```

Output:-

```
Date      A   
2019-51  10 
2019-52  10
2020-01  10
2020-02  10
2020-03  10
2020-04  20
```

I need pandas python code to generate the above output

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it meant to provide personalized guides and tutorials. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC we use `resample`

```
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.Date+'0',format = '%Y-%W%w')
df=df.resample('W').ffill()
df.index=df.index.strftime('%Y-%W')
df=df.drop('Date',1).reset_index()
df
Out[57]: 
     index   A
0  2019-51  10
1  2020-00  10# this not ISO week
2  2020-01  10
3  2020-02  10
4  2020-03  10
5  2020-04  20
```

If you would like from 01

```
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.Date+'0',format = '%G-%V%w')
df=df.resample('W').ffill()
df.index=df.index.strftime('%Y-%V')
df=df.drop('Date',1).reset_index()
df
Out[62]: 
     index   A
0  2019-51  10
1  2019-52  10
2  2020-01  10
3  2020-02  10
4  2020-03  10
5  2020-04  20
```

Comment: TIL.  So adding the `0` **AND** the `'%w'` (that's lower case w) tells `to_datetime` that this is the first day of the week.  That along with the week number gives Pandas enough specificity to parse the date.  See strformat.org for more info on formatting strings.  So the format string can be interpreted as `'four-digit-year, dash, week number, day of week'`

Comment: But my output is different     Date      A   
2019-51  10 
2019-52  10
2020-01  10
2020-02  10
2020-03  10
2020-04  20

Comment: @ankitsaxena run the code.  YOBEN_S just didn't update the output.

Comment: @ankitsaxena I've run and verified the output and have edited the post.

Comment: Thanks YOBEN_S and @piRSquared